# How do I use sed on a string?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use sed with strings in a bash script without having to read or write to any files. I googled around and I couldn't find anything

Specifically I am trying to get the number of files in a given directory by doing somethign like:

```
RAW=$(ls $DIRNAME | wc)
# RAW --> ? sed ? --> answer
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not `sed`, but it is better for this problem.

`ls | wc -l`

In general, `sed` takes a string as input.  For example,

`ls | sed 's/\./Period replaced by sed/g'`

Answer (score 1):

`answer=$(echo $RAW|sed <YOURSTUFF>)`

Comment: Ah! I tried doing:

    ls $DIRNAME | wc > sed <...>

that was really stupid of me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls` and `wc` to do this.

`\ls | wc -l`

Comment: When `ls` is not outputting directly to a terminal, it only prints one file / line anyway, the `-1` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
ls -1R | wc -l
```

To store the count in a variable, you can write something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

total=`ls -1R | wc -l`   # stores the count in $total

echo $total              # prints the count
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the `ls ... | wc ...` solutions will fail for files containing newlines. This will only fail if the directory is empty:

```
set -- *
printf "%d\n" "$#"
```

or if you want to include dot (hidden) files:

```
set -- .* *
printf "%d\n" "$#"
```

That will include . and .., so subtract 2 if that's undesirable (which it probably is)

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses wc and also works if there a files with new lines in their name:

```
 find  .  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c
```